# C++ output stream floating point call chain

Tags: c++, iostream

In C++, when I do

```
std::cout << 1.2;
```

what is the actual chain of functions that are called to actually display the number? I realize this is compiler specific, but I am interested in particular with the Gnu libstdc++ implementation.

In C, calling printf delegates to vfprintf, which through jump tables calls __printf_fp in glibc. I'm looking for an analogous chain in the pure C++ setting.

Comment: As you said <quote>I realize this is compiler specific</quote>. Not only that but version specific. This kind of information is not useful.

Comment: Really any version would do. The point is not precision but rather to get an idea of which library layers the functions tunnel through. I have a vague impression that `locale` is involved.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Clearly, it will call [ostream::operator<<](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/iostream/ostream/operator%3C%3C/) first but it may be library specific beyond that. The best way to answer this is to debug into the code and follow the functions as they occur. This will not only tell you what functions are called but tell your about edge cases and error handling that occurs. Looking at the code may help but it is likely convoluted.

Using this code:

```
std::cout << 1.2f;
```

... here is what is does in Visual Studio 2012 without the noise:

1. [operator<<(float _Val)](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/iostream/ostream/operator%3C%3C/) (std::basic_ostream<_Elem, _Traits>)

   1. Initialize a [state](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/iostream/ios_base/iostate/) variable to [good](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/iostream/ios/good/).
   2. Call [use_facet<_Facet>(const locale & _Loc)](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/std/locale/use_facet/) (std) to get the num_put facet.
   3. Call [num_put(_OutIt _Dest, ios_base& _Iosbase, _Elem _Fill, double _Val)](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/std/locale/num_put/put/) (std) to write the float to the output stream (converted to a double) using local specific formatting. Internally, this:

      1. Checks the [precision](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/iostream/ios_base/precision/), such [fixed](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/iostream/manipulators/fixed/), to see if the default formatting has been modified.
      2. Formats the number and writes it to the output as characters to the current iterator used by the stream.
   4. Set the state variable to [bad](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/iostream/ios/bad/) if the operation failed.
   5. Call [setstate](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/iostream/ios/setstate/) to the state.

So most of the work is actually done in the num_put facet, which writes to an iterator for the output stream.

Comment: Compiling and running a simple program with debugging does not allow me to step into the library routines.

Comment: If your compiler or library does not allow debugging into it, perhaps look at the source code, such as http://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/libstdc++/libstdc++-html-USERS-3.4/ostream-source.html.

Comment: Don't you think I've tried that? The source code for the standard C++ libraries is incredibly convoluted, and the only reason I'm asking the question in the first place is because I'm hoping there's an expert here that can give me a bit of guidance. Right now, I'm tracing operator<< back to the use of facets, which is obtained from a locale object... and I'm not even sure I'm interpreting what I see correctly.

Comment: I understand your frustration. I am no STL expert but I have looked through the code in Visual Studio and attempted to give more detail. What you have described in the comment above is correct.