# what is __printf_fp() and when is it called?

Tags: c++, callgrind

After using callgrind to profile my code, I see that __printf_fp() is the function with more value in the self column. What is this function and when is it called?

Thank you!

Comment: Any identifier including two consecutive underscores is reserved for the compiler & standard library, so it's probably an internal routine of your standard library. Look for details there. But judging from the name, it's probably a subroutine of `printf`.

Comment: I deleted the post since I got the answer by checking the calls graph. It is used by ofstream in my case which I forgot I was using in my code. I undeleted the post since your answer could be useful for anybody. Thank you!

Comment: I don't think my comment is enough for a full answer, but you can self-answer your question (there's a certain timeout since posting after which that's possible), and incorporate what parts of it you consider relevant.

Comment: Why the downvotes? I thought it was more honest to edit the post instead of posting a self-reply, which makes not too much sense for me.

Comment: This is first and foremost a Q&A site - editing answers into questions is discouraged, while self-answers are actually rather encouraged. And I think that while not too broad, the question (with an answer) can still be useful. (Note: I didn't downvote you, of course).

Comment: Ok I will add the answer when I can because of the time restriction. Thank you once again :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`__printf_pf()` belongs to the libstdc++ library. It is mainly called by any printf related function (ostream, ofstream, etc). However, when it is called depends on the compiler and compiler's version as pointed out here: [C++ output stream floating point call chain](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12699876/c-output-stream-floating-point-call-chain)